# Python: Write to global text file from within a multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, io, multiprocessing

I'd like to launch a mp.Process which can write to a text file. But I'm finding that at the end of the script, the data written to the file isn't actually saved to disk. I don't know what's happening. Here's a minimum working example:

```
import os, time, multiprocessing

myfile = open("test.dat", "w")

def main():

    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer)
    proc.start()

    time.sleep(1)
    print "Times up! Closing file..."
    myfile.flush()
    os.fsync(myfile.fileno())
    print "Closing %s" % (myfile)
    myfile.close()
    print "File closed. Have a nice day!"
    print "> cat test.dat"

def writer():
    data = "0000"
    for _ in xrange(5):
        print "Writing %s to %s" % (data, myfile)
        myfile.write(str(data) + '\n')
        # if you comment me, writing to disk works!
        # myfile.flush()
        # os.fsync(myfile.fileno())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Does anyone have suggestions? The context is that this Process will be eventually listening for incoming data, so it really needs to run independently of other things happening in the script.

Comment: Just ran your code, worked for me.  What if you give it more time?

Comment: The code runs normally, but for me the output file (test.dat) is empty. Do you find a non-empty file?

Comment: Yup my file had four rows in it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're opening the file in the main process. Open files are not passed to the subprocesses, so you need to open it inside your function.

Also every code outside the function is executed once for each process, so you're overwriting the file multiple times.

```
def main():
    # create the file empty so it can be appended to
    open("test.dat", "w").close()
    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=writer)
    proc.start()

def writer():
    with open('test.dat', 'a') as myfile: # opens the file for appending
        ...
        myfile.write(...)
        ...
```

Now, some OSes don't allow a file to be opened by multiple processes at the same time. The best solution is to use a Queue and pass the data to the main process which then writes to the file.

Comment: Hmm. I think you're correct, but then I'm confused as to why the print statements say the function is writing to an open file:

`Writing 0000 to <open file 'test.dat', mode 'w' at 0x10f9d05d0>`

And also, if I flush the file from within writer, the output is correctly written to file. So something is happening correctly, but something else is happening incorrectly. I don't understand the subtlety.

Comment: @AlexTuna as I said, the code outside the function runs once for each process. Your code overwrites the file every time a new process is created

Comment: I don't agree that the new process overwrites the file. Try adding this in `main()`:

`multiprocessing.Process(target=writer).start() ; time.sleep(1) ;  multiprocessing.Process(target=writer).start() ; time.sleep(1)`

and then uncomment the `flush` and `fsync` commands in `writer()`. You'll see both Proc's successfully write to the file. They aren't overwriting each other. Am I missing something?